# IE 10 pending XMLHttpRequest for 6 minutes and then answers the request (CRSF implementation with AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

**Task description**

I implemented CRSF protection for my angular application. The server checks if the crsf token is placed in the header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN' of the request. If not it sends a http response 403.

Ïn my client I intercept all requests and check if a http response 403 is returned. In this case I send a HEAD request in order to get the crsf token from the server which is returned in the header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN' of the response.

After getting the token from the server, I resend the original request with the given crsf token in the header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.

**Problem description**

This works fine with all browsers except with internet explorer (tried IE 9 and 10). Locally (without proxy and firewall) it also works with internet explorer. But in our production environment the head request is **pending for 360s, but then returns the expected response**.

I'm not sure what is happening. Why does it work on localhost but not in the production environment? Could it be a problem of the proxy? But why it works with all other browsers (chrome, firefox, ...)? And even after 6 minutes the IE is getting a correct answer and proceeds as expected. For me it does not look like a proxy problem. So, is it a problem with the IE? But why is it working on localhost?

The only difference in the request of IE and other browser is the referer in the header:
 - in IE the referer looks like http://url/context-root/#/login
 - in other browsers the referer looks like http://url/context-root/

The difference between local environment and production environment is, that the proxy intercepts the requests and does some context-rewriting and opens a https tunnel. The server actually uses http, the proxy is then tunneling the requests.

Has anyone an idea what the problem could be?

Here is my angular module which registers the http-interceptor:

```
'use strict';
(function () {
     angular.module('csrf-token-interceptor', [])
         .config(function ($httpProvider) {
             var csrfToken = { headerName: 'X-CSRF-TOKEN', token: null };
             var getCsrfToken = function () {
                 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                 xhr.open('head', '/context-root/index.html?id=' + new Date().toString(), false);
                 xhr.send();
                 return { headerName: 'X-CSRF-TOKEN', token: xhr.getResponseHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN') };
             };
             var numRetries = 0;
             var MAX_RETRIES = 1;
             $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q, $injector) {
                 return {
                     request: function (config) {
                         config.headers[csrfToken.headerName] = csrfToken.token;
                         return config || $q.when(config);
                     },
                     responseError: function (response) {
                         if (response.status === 403 && numRetries < MAX_RETRIES) {
                             csrfToken = getCsrfToken();
                             var $http = $injector.get('$http');
                             ++numRetries;
                             return $http(response.config);
                         }
                         return $q.reject(response);
                     },
                     response: function(response) {
                         numRetries = 0;
                         var newToken = response.headers(csrfToken.headerName);
                         if (newToken !== null) {
                             csrfToken.token = newToken;
                         }
                         return response;
                     }
                 };
             });
         });
 })();
```

The requests looks at follows:

- POST http://url/context-root/#/login, Time: **53ms**,  Status: **403**
- HEAD http://url/context-root/index.html?id=..., Time: **360,2s**, Status: **200**
- POST http://url/context-root/#/login, Time: **49ms**, Status: **200**

Comment: Can you share the requests in a more useful format (e.g. Fiddler `.SAZ` or HTTP Archive `.har`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *may* be a bug in IE related to your use of the `HEAD` method; see https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1023203/xhr-readystate-done-delay-on-head-request

Have you observed your network traffic with a proxy like Fiddler? If so, can you share a traffic capture?

Comment: I added the requests to the questions

Comment: What you added doesn't show the HTTP version number, which would reveal whether this is the known IE bug.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't reading your answer right. This could be indeed the problem. Locally it uses HTTP/1.1 and in production environment it uses HTTP/1.0. Seems like the proxy is using HTTP/1.0. I will try the solution provided in the bug report and will then share if it has worked